# Datatables, how to change appearance

Tags: javascript, css, plugins

How you can see i use datatables to style my tables:

[image]
What disturbs me is **first**, that the plugin adds an line above my table:

```
Showing 1  to 14 of 14 entries
```

How do i have to cahnge my code, so that this wont be displayed anymore?

**Next** problem is that i styled my rows with backgound-colors, but how you can see when i press on one of the headings for example "typ", datatables overwrites my colors with the standard blue tones!

My code: Thanks to all!

```
 jQuery ->
$('#treatment').dataTable
"bPaginate": false,
"sScrollY": "400px",
    "bScrollCollapse": true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in order to remove the 'entries' info, you must add the option 'bInfo' with the value of 'false':

```
jQuery ->
$('#treatment').dataTable
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sScrollY": "400px",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "bInfo": false // to disable the entries info.
```

Its always a good idea to read [the documentation](https://datatables.net/ref).

Lastly, given you have not given a complete reproduction of your experienced problem, the following is a shot in the dark based on the limited information provided;

You may wish to modify/add the css classes to your own css file that is included last in the document, `tr.odd.gradeA td.sorting_1` and `tr.even.gradeA td.sorting_1`.

Always remember to inspect the elements with your browser's development tools, which would allow you to see which classes you need to modify, and which options to search for in the documentation.